# How to easily pass a variable into a .sass file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Inside of a Rails project, there is a variable to say what site we want the Rails app to run as -- for example, for cars, or boats, and
there should be a different CSS sprites if it is a car site or a boat site (site logo is inside the sprite).   What is a good way to pass this variable's value: "cars" or "boats"
into the .sass file so that the .sass file will use the sprite   `public/images/sprites/sprite-cars.png` or `public/images/sprites/sprite-boats.png`?

One possible way is to use this in an init file in `config/initializers`

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:load_paths] = ["#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/views/templates/#{SITE_NAME}/"]
```

and inside of `app/views/templates/cars/` put a `_site_variables.sass` there and add a line

```
@import "site_variables"
```

in the main .sass file.  In `_site_variables.sass`, just have

```
$site_sprite_path: '/images/sprites/sprites-cars.png'
```

This works, but it is a lot of work to just pass a variable.  Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to define a custom Sass function (see [the documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html)) and use the `:custom` option to pass in your specific variables.

Comment: Hi @動靜能量, can you please put up a sample code of what you did for this? I need the same thing, and i am not able to figure out the best possible way?

Answer (score 6):

The Sass documentation describes how to add [custom functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions) and mentions an option [`:custom`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#custom-option) for custom configuration variables.

Suppose, for example, you want a function to display the current year.  Make a file `lib/sass_year.rb` containing the following:

```
require 'sass'
require 'sass/script'

module Sass::Script::Functions
  def year
    Sass::Script::Value::String.new(Sass::Plugin.options[:custom][:year])
  end
end
```

Then, in some place like `environment.rb`, include and configure it as follows:

```
require Rails.root+'lib/sass_year'
require 'sass/plugin'
Sass::Plugin.options[:custom] ||= {}
Sass::Plugin.options[:custom][:year] = Time.now.year.to_s
```

Now you can use the function within Sass code like this:

```
div#copyright
  content: "© 2001&ndash;#{year()} XYZ Corporation"
```

Instead of the current year, you could access environment variables or other configuration data.  Note that without the `to_s` you will get a corrupted string, and when debugging make sure to periodically clear out `tmp/cache` to force regeneration of your stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I hate to undermine @pdg137's answer but my code is too big for a comment. Upvote him please! I wouldn't have got here without him.

---

Here's my implementation:

*sass_helper.rb*

```
require 'sass'
require 'sass/script'

module SassHelper
  def generateHash
    "asdf"
  end

  module Sass::Script::Functions
    def foo()
      Sass::Script::Value::String.new(options[:custom][:test])
    end
  end
end
```

*foo.html.erb*

```
se = Sass::Engine.for_file('foo.scss', :syntax => :scss, :custom => { :test => generateHash })
```

*foo.scss*

```
body-#{foo()} { ... }
```

This exposes a hash generation method externally that I can use to pass as an option to be consumed by the SASS interpolation.

[Calling SCSS functions from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147484/calling-scss-functions-from-ruby) explains that you can't call external methods because there's an `ExecutionContext`, which in turn explains the runaround with `:custom` and `options`.