# Calling SCSS functions from Ruby

Tags: ruby, sass

I am trying to call darken from Ruby.

Here is my code:

```
Sass::Script::Functions.darken('#FF0000', '20%')
```

I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `darken' for Sass::Script::Functions:Module
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

`Sass::Script::Functions` is a module with instance methods, it's meant to be included in another object.  Unfortunately when you do that, it needs other methods to work.  There's an `EvaluationContext` object in there too, and extending that gets `darken` to run, but fails when it asserts the types of objects intended to be passed.

```
class C < Sass::Script::Functions::EvaluationContext
  def initialize
    super :global
  end  
  def x
    darken('#FF0000', '20%')    
  end  
end  

> C.new.x
ArgumentError: $color: "#FF0000" is not a color
```

What are you trying to accomplish?  It does not appear that Sass is meant to be called in this way.

Comment: I am trying to use the darken function with interpolation and regular css.

Comment: ["not a color" error explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312338/sass-for-loop-updating-hsla-lightness-returns-error-lightness-96-77419-is-no)

Comment: Well, kinda.  It's meant to be used inside Sass's parser where the value would be passed as a color object.  You can see the `assert_type` checks on all the parameters.  This is just simply not how it's meant to be used.